# Google App Scripts - Copy file into folder with names from ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm working in Google Sheets and I'm trying to create a script that will make a set number of copies of the current file, giving each copy the next name from a list of names in a range, and place those files in folders that were created by a previous script. I was able to get it all working, but only for the first file (out of 6, and possible far more) and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
[Here's a copy of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l7Rf-dk_2QLFiyc0rwzp8GJo5pEXP7cVkhGWFx9JT74/edit?usp=sharing). I also have another version of this that works to just create copies of the document, but I'm trying to streamline the process for my end users who may be creating dozens of copies and was hoping that doing the organization for them would help.

Thanks for your help!

Here's the script:

```
function createcopies2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get the range of cells that store necessary data.
var CoachNames = ss.getRangeByName("CoachNames");

var CoachObjects = CoachNames.getValues();

var schoolNames = ss.getRangeByName("SchoolNames");

var SchoolObjects = schoolNames.getValues();

var id = ss.getId();  
// The next variable gets a value that counts how many CoachNames there are in the spreadsheet
var coaches = ss.getRangeByName("Coaches");

var numcoaches = coaches.getValue();

//here's the function
for(i=0; i<numcoaches; i++){ 

var drive=DriveApp.getFileById(id);

var name=CoachObjects[i].toString();

var folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SchoolObjects[i]).next();

var folderid=folder.getId();

var folder2=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)
if(folder) {
drive.makeCopy(name, folder2)}
else{
drive.makeCopy(name);
}

return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.
I have modified you below, with explanation:

```
function createcopies2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get the range of cells that store necessary data.
var CoachNames = ss.getRangeByName("CoachNames");
//The below statements a 2D dimensional array.
//To access the individual value you will have a statement like this
//CoachObjects[0][0],CoachObject[1][0],[2][0] ..., down the row
var CoachObjects = CoachNames.getValues();

var schoolNames = ss.getRangeByName("SchoolNames");
//The below statements a 2D dimensional array.
var SchoolObjects = schoolNames.getValues();

var id = ss.getId();  
// The next variable gets a value that counts how many CoachNames there are in the spreadsheet
var coaches = ss.getRangeByName("Coaches");

var numcoaches = coaches.getValue();
//Moved the below statement out of the loop
// Baceause you are using the same file
var drive=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
//here's the function
for(i=0; i<numcoaches; i++){ 
var name=CoachObjects[i][0].toString();

var folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SchoolObjects[i][0]).next();

var folderid=folder.getId();

var folder2=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)
if(folder) {
drive.makeCopy(name, folder2)}
else{
drive.makeCopy(name);
}

return;
}
}
```

I modified the code since you get a 2D array from getValues

```
//The below statements a 2D dimensional array.

var CoachObjects = CoachNames.getValues();
```

To access the individual value you will use a statement like this

```
`CoachObjects[0][0]`
 CoachObjects[1][0]
 .......     [2][0] ...
 down the row
```

Also, These are redundant lines of code:

```
var folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SchoolObjects[i][0]).next();
var folderid=folder.getId();
var folder2=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)
```

you can just replace it with

```
var folder2=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SchoolObjects[i][0]).next();
```